# Cannot include String in my data constructor?

Tags: haskell

I want to include String as part of my constructor:

```
> data Car = Wheel | Trunk | String deriving (Show)

> test::Car->Car->Car
> test Wheel Wheel = "Wheel"
> test _ _ = ""
```

it says: Couldn't match Car with [Char]

if I change the constructor to

```
> data Car = Wheel | Trunk | [Char] deriving (Show)
```

it says: error in constructor in data/newtype declaration: [Char]

So how do I create a data type where one of the constructors is also a string?

Comment: What you have done in the first is create a value constructor called `String`. That is `String :: Car`. If you wanted to actually include a `String` type value, you would specify a value constructor like `CarStr String` or `String String` but the latter case is slightly confusing.

Comment: @Sarah, I just want to be able to return a value of type string, and sometimes Wheel or Trunk, from methods returning type Car. Do I have to use type parameters here?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You clearly specified that `test` should yield a `Car` value. If you have a value constructor in the `Car` type that is `CarStr String`, you just return `CarStr "Wheel"` or whatever you want. You can then pattern match out that `String` for whatever purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell does not provide unnamed unions as you have used in your `Car` data type. Each element in the definition of a data type must have a constructor. For example, you could define the following data type.

```
data Car = Wheel | Trunk | Constr String
```

In this definition `Constr` denotes a constructor and `String` is the type of its argument. For example, you can construct a value of type `Car` by using `Constr "Wheel"`. If you omit the `String` in the example above, it is a constructor called `Constr` without an argument. Similarly, in your example, `String` is a constructor, even if there exists a type with the same name.

With the definition of `Car` above, you can define `test` as follows.

```
test :: Car -> Car -> Car
test Wheel Wheel = Constr "Wheel"
test _     _     = Constr ""
```

By adding the constructor `String` on the right hand side of the definitions, the string is lifted into the `Car` data type. However, as mentioned in the comments, a definition like this seems a little odd as `test` always yields a value of type `String`. Therefore, another possible definition would be the following.

```
test :: Car -> Car -> String
test Wheel Wheel = "Wheel"
test _     _     = ""
```

Comment: That might have indeed been foolish, I have edited that part.

Answer (score 1):

> data Car = Wheel | Trunk | String deriving (Show)

here you are declaring `Car` with constructors `Wheel`, `Trunk` and **`String`**. Your `String` differs from the standard String type, therefore they're not the same. So you can't simply match that with a String such as `""`. If you want to give it a string value, make the constructor accepts a string, e.g.:

```
data Car = Wheel | Trunk | CarName String deriving (Show)
```

and you can then use it like:

```
test::Car->Car->Car
test Wheel Wheel = CarName "Wheel"
test _ _ = CarName ""
```

the result of this function must be matched against the constructors, e.g.:

```
let x = test Wheel Wheel 
in case x of
     Wheel -> ... -- do something if it's wheel
     Trunk -> ... -- do something if it's trunk
     CarName x -> ... -- do something if it's carname, you can use the returned x
```